# alsa gives error when run via su

Tags: linux, opensuse, alsa

I have a script that starts my application

```
./run_se
```

and it works just fine. But I want to start it at system boot, so in after.boot, I have

```
su artisan -c "/home/artisan/run_se"
```

but this errors out, alsa claiming

```
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1693:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
```

when I try to open the output device.
I displayed the user and group in the script, and they are as expected (artisan/user). How is this job started from su different than the same job started as user artisan, why doesn't alsa like it, and how can I get alsa to run when started at boot time? (I also tried adding -l to the su command)

openSUSE 13.2, system created from Suse Studio, JeOS

Edit:
It's getting weirder. If I ssh to the box as root, I can run the program without error. However, if I Alt-F3 and login as root, the program errors. If I login as artisan and then su to root, the program does not error.

I'm suspecting systemd (which has already bitten me once), but my reading and googling and grepping hasn't found the smoking gun yet.

Comment: Check the permissions (including ACLs) on the device files in `/dev/snd/`.

Comment: Nothing important there, although you did send me on a learning journey :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a combination of a silly error by me and a continuing mystery.

The silly error is that I did not have artisan as a member of the audio group. But I was confused by...

The mystery is why running a program acts differently when running from a terminal window than it does from ssh. And why running that program causes an error when the user running it is root. I still don't understand that, but will ignore it since I can now continue.

Comment: Some distributions automatically give console users access to the audio devices when logging in.

Comment: How does that work? Is it by group membership? If so, is there a command that shows effective group membership? Is there a configuration file somewhere that enables this?

Comment: IIRC they add entries to the device files' ACLs.